# Newbie: Performance Analysis through the command line

Tags: c++, c, performance

I am looking for a performance analysis tool with the following properties:

1. Free.
2. Runs on Windows.
3. Does not require using the GUI
   (i.e. can be run from command line or by using some library in any programming language).
4. Runs on some x86-based architecture (preferably Intel).
5. Can measure the running time of my C++, mingw-compiled, program, except for the time spent in a few certain functions I specify (and all calls emanating from them).
6. Can measure the amount of memory used by my program, except for the memory allocated by those functions I specified in (5) and all calls emanating from them.

A tool that have properties (1) to (5) (without 6) can still be very valuable to me.

My goal is to be able to compare the running time and memory usage of different programs in a consistent way (i.e. the main requirement is that timing the same program twice would return roughly the same results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mingw should already have a **gprof** tool. To use it you just need to compile with correct flags set. I think it was `-g -pg`.

Answer (score 1):

For heap analysis (free) you can use [umdh.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268343) which is a full heap dumper, you can also compare consecutive memory snapshots to check for leakage over time.  You'd have to filter the output yourself to remove functions that were not of interest, however.

I know that's not exactly what you were asking for in (6), but it might be useful.  I think filtering like this is not going to be so common in freeware.